# Time JSON marshals to 0 time

Tags: json, go, time

I have the following code which primarily marshals and un-marshals a time struct. Here is the code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "encoding/json"
)

type check struct{
    A time.Time `json:"a"`
}

func main(){
    ds := check{A:time.Now().Truncate(0)}
    fmt.Println(ds)
    dd, _ := json.Marshal(ds)
    d2 := check {}
    json.Unmarshal(dd, d2)
    fmt.Println(d2)
}
```

here is the output it produces

```
{2019-05-20 15:20:16.247914 +0530 IST}
{0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC}
```

The first line is the original time and the second line is the time after the unmarshalling. Why do we have this loss of information with `JSON` conversions? How to prevent this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go vet tells you exactly what the problem is:

> ./prog.go:18:16: call of Unmarshal passes non-pointer as second argument

Also **never** ignore errors! The least you can do is print it:

```
ds := check{A: time.Now().Truncate(0)}
fmt.Println(ds)
dd, err := json.Marshal(ds)
fmt.Println(err)
d2 := check{}
err = json.Unmarshal(dd, d2)
fmt.Println(err)
fmt.Println(d2)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pr4VGTvZRzO)):

```
{2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC}
<nil>
json: Unmarshal(non-pointer main.check)
{0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC}
```

You have to pass a **pointer** to [`json.Unmarshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) for it to be able to unmarshal into (change) your value:

```
err = json.Unmarshal(dd, &d2)
```

With this change  output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/NucgEZ4ai1A)):

```
{2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC}
<nil>
<nil>
{2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC}
```

Comment: I feel dumb now. First I should have not ignored the error and should have checked for error myself and second I should have initialised d2 to a pointer itself. Thanks for answering.